# How to restrict the @parma of javadoc to have comments in checkstyle

Tags: java, checkstyle, intellij-plugin, maven-checkstyle-plugin

How to restrict the @parma of javadoc to have comments in checkstyle

such as

```
/**
 * text
 * @param args  //Error reported here, must have comment
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {}
```

Comment: I suppose you mean `@param`, but it would help if you would say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use NonEmptyAtclauseDescription, https://checkstyle.org/config_javadoc.html#NonEmptyAtclauseDescription

```
$ cat TestClass.java
public class TestClass {
    /**
     * text.
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {}
}

$ cat TestConfig.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC
          "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Check Configuration 1.3//EN"
          "https://checkstyle.org/dtds/configuration_1_3.dtd">

<module name="Checker">
    <property name="charset" value="UTF-8"/>

    <module name="TreeWalker">
<module name="NonEmptyAtclauseDescription"/>
    </module>
</module>

$ java -jar checkstyle-10.1-all.jar -c TestConfig.xml TestClass.java
Starting audit...
[ERROR] TestClass.java:4: At-clause should have a non-empty description. [NonEmptyAtclauseDescription]
Audit done.
Checkstyle ends with 1 errors.
```